# Pagination Apollo Client 3 - Cache merges but does not render new results when paginating

Tags: apollo-client

I'd love to implement nested pagination within my application. I have been reading the docs and looking at several other examples but I just can't get this to work - any help is appreciated! Thanks!

React component:
I am clicking the button to run the `fetchMore` function provided by the `useQuery` hook (apollo). The network request is going through and the new products are merged into the cache... but no new products render on the page.

```
export const FilterableKit = () => {
  const selectedKitId = useReactiveVar(selectedKitIdVar);

  const [
    getKitProducts,
    { data: getKitProductsData, loading: getKitProductsLoading, fetchMore },
  ] = useGetKitProductsLazyQuery();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedKitId) {
      getKitProducts({
        variables: {
          getKitsInput: {
            _id: {
              string: selectedKitId,
              filterBy: "OBJECTID" as StringFilterByEnum,
            },
          },
          getProductsInput: {
            config: {
              pagination: {
                reverse: true,
                limit: 3,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
    }
  }, [getKitProducts, selectedKitId]);

  const kitProducts = getKitProductsData?.getKits.data?.find(
    (kit) => kit?._id === selectedKitId
  )?.products.data;

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    if (kitProducts && kitProducts?.length > 0) {
      const remaining =
        getKitProductsData?.getKits.data[0]?.products.stats?.remaining;

      if (remaining && remaining > 0) {
        const cursor =
          kitProducts[kitProducts.length - 1] &&
          kitProducts[kitProducts.length - 1]?.createdAt;

        fetchMore({
          variables: {
            getProductsInput: {
              config: {
                pagination: {
                  reverse: true,
                  createdAt: cursor,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <CContainer>
      <KitItemCards products={kitProducts} loading={getKitProductsLoading} />
      <CContainer className="d-flex justify-content-center my-3">
        <CButton color="primary" className="w-100" onClick={handleLoadMore}>
          Load More
        </CButton>
      </CContainer>
    </CContainer>
  );
};
```

Type Policies: I define the "Kit" typePolicy to merge products into the correct field.

```
export const cache: InMemoryCache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Kit: {
      fields: {
        products: {
          keyArgs: false,
          merge(existing = [] as Product[], incoming: GetProductsResponse) {
            if (!incoming) return existing;
            if (!existing) return incoming;

            const { data: products, ...rest } = incoming;
            let result: any = rest;
            result = [...existing, ...(products ?? [])];

            return result;
          },
        },
      },
    },
});
```

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction! Let me know if there is something else you'd like to see.

Comment: I had the same problem... passing an updateQuery function as an option to the fetchMore function worked, but I don't think that's the proper way in v3. 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/api/react-apollo/#datafetchmoreoptions